# how can i check that my value is null or not in dynamic generated html table

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my code that i used to genrate html table using javascipt

now my problem is i want to put **"--"** insted of "**null**" value,so how can i 
check the value that null or not before code should displayed.

```
   var res1 = sessionStorage.getItem('user_list');
            var res = JSON.parse(res1);
            var createList = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {

                createList += "   <div class='table-data-banner'>    <div class='div-block switch'>\
                    <div data-ix='switch' class='switch-click-area'>\
                    <div class='switch-length'><div class='switch-bulb'>\
                    </div>\
                    </div>\
                    </div>\
    </div>\
                     <a href='#' class='table-data-link'  style='max-width:100%' >\
                          <input type='hidden' class='user_id'  value=" + res[i].user_id + "  \> \
    <div class='text-block-2 data first'>" + res[i].first_name + "</div><div class='text-block-2 first data'>" + res[i].last_name + "</div>\
    <div class='text-block-2 email no-mobile data'>" + res[i].email_id + "</div>\
    <div class='text-block-2 phone no-mobile data'>" + res[i].cell_phone + "</div>\
    <div class='text-block-2 access no-mobile data'>" + res[i].access_level + "</div>\
    <div class='text-block-2 access no-mobile data'>\
    <input type='button' class='w-button delete-data' value='delete' user_id=" + res[i].user_id + " postion=" + i + "> &nbsp; \
    <input type='button' class='w-button edit-data' value='edit' user_id=" + res[i].user_id + " postion=" + i + "></div>\
    \
    </a>   </div>"
            }
```

Comment: Something like `(res[i].first_name || "--")` for each property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the falsy nature of JS to coalesce `null` or `undefined` values to `'--'`, like this:

```
'<input type="hidden" class="user_id" value="' + (res[i].user_id || '--') + '"  \>'
```

Also note that I'd suggest you use templating logic to build your HTML, as having that much UI code within the JS is not ideal.

Comment: its worked for me thank you and i will tack care of this next time

Answer (score 0):

I'd program it more functionally using the map function and template literals for better readibility

```
   var res1 = sessionStorage.getItem('user_list');
   const list = JSON.parse(res1)
     .map(item => { 
        return `<div class='table-data-banner'>
         <div class='div-block switch'>
         ... (template markup here)
           <input type='hidden' class='user_id'  value="${(item.user_id || '--')}"\> 
          ..(template markup here)
          </div>` 
      })
```